# Why error when read_csv in pandas?

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file in pandas but keep getting an error:

```
df_cut= pd.read_csv('cut.csv', header='None', nrows = 100)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `header=None`, without quotes?

Comment: Yes, of course. No quotes. Thank you. I was so stupid.